# Does anyone know of a resource that lists 'root morphemes' of latin words?

Tags: morphology

I having been searching the web like crazy trying to find a resource that list Latin root morphemes. That is, words which all share the same base meaning and are listed in their word families. 
For example, 'candere', 'candescens', 'candidus', share the same base meaning. 
As with, 'fabrica', 'fabri', 'fabricare'.
Does anyone know of a resource that groups words in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latin Wiktionary lists "Related Terms" & "Descendants"; so do the most expensive dictionaries.

Comment: L&S also, which is I believe in the public domain